# HandleModalPopping issue in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have a problem in my project, everything working fine but just there is an issue that when i PopModalAsync the page by using this code

```
this.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

the HandleModalPopping fucnction called more than one time , it should be 1 time only,
i mean this fucntion below.

```
private void HandleModalPopping(object sender, ModalPoppingEventArgs e)
{
        GV.DoubleClicled = false;
}
```

and this how i declaration the function in the constracotr of the page after
InitializeComponent(); method

```
  PhotoHandle.App.Current.ModalPopping += HandleModalPopping;
```

**note : if i open the page 1 time and close it , the HandleModalPopping fucnction called one time,
and everytime i open and close the page its increase the number of calls!!**

can i know whats the problem or why thats issue happed?

thank you.

Comment: `ModalPopping` is an event on the `Application` object, meaning it applies throughout your app, not just on that single page.  So when you assign a new event handler in the page constructor, it is added to the existing set of event handlers.

Comment: first , thank you for your answer, and how can i let it on the single page?

Comment: unsubscribe from the event when you are done with it

Comment: override `OnDisappearing` method of page, put `PhotoHandle.App.Current.ModalPopping -= HandleModalPopping;` there.